# errors in parameter expansion on filenames named after negative numbers

Tags: bash, filenames

I have some files under a directory:

```
$ ls *
-008.png  0052.png -002.jpg  0043.png  -005.png  0044.png ...
```

I would like to copy the files to a subdirectory `subdir` (without overwriting existing files), and rename the files by adding a given number (say 10) to their filename, so that the files becomes

```
$ ls subdir/*
0002.png  0062.png 0008.jpg  0053.png  0005.png  0054.png ...
```

Here is my bash command

```
for filename in *
do
basename=${filename%.*}
extname=${filename#*.}
basename_new=$(printf %04d $((10#${basename}+10))); # 10#-008: value too great for base (error token is "003")
if [ ! -e subdir/"$basename_new".* ];  # [: subdir/.: binary operator expected
cp "$filename" "$basename_new"."$extname"
fi
done
```

For some files whose names are negative numbers, I got errors, for example for `-008.png` (but not for `-002.png`, and I am not sure why):

for the line that assigns to `basename_new`:

```
10#-008: value too great for base (error token is "008")
```

for the line with `if`:

```
# [: subdir/.: binary operator expected
```

I was wondering what those errors mean? How may I solve them?

Thanks.

Comment: My best direction at this point is to do something like `[[ $b =~ ^-0+([0-9]+)$ ]] && b=-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to strip leading zeroes from possibly-negative numbers

Comment: Thanks.  Is `[[ $b =~ ^-0+([0-9]+)$ ]] && b=-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` same as `[[ $b =~ ^-0+([1-9]+)$ ]] && b=-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479986/is-pattern-00-9-the-same-as-01-9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A word beginning with a dash is generally considered as an option. When you do `ls *`, the `ls` command receives `ls 001.png -002.png ...` and sees `-002.png` as a set of options it does not understand. Same for many commands like `cp`, `mv`, ...

Solution #1: prefix the files with their path. Will work in all cases.

```
ls ./*
```

Solution #2: a lot of commands, especially in the GNU world, accept a double-dash as a parameter, indicating that what follows are not options

```
ls -- *
```

However, leading dashes won't affect you `for` loop.

---

As for the "value too great for base", it is due to `-008` being considered as an octal number because it begins with a 0. However 8 is not a valid octal digit. A quick fix would be to use `bc`:

```
printf -v basename_new %04d "$(bc <<< "${basename} + 10")"
```

You issue with `if` is caused by an empty `basename_new` and will disappear with the fix above.

Comment: though I think the main question seems to be about the negative leading-zero number confusing bash's arithmetic (despite the attempted base conversion), not any option-confusion with `ls`

Comment: Thanks. The error is from running the for loop at the end, not running ls.

Comment: Sorry @Tim, I was not careful enough. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `-008` is considered as an octal number, while other positive numbers are not?

Comment: @Tim Numbers starting with `0x` are hexadecimal numbers. Numbers starting with `0` are octal numbers. Other numbers are decimal numbers.

Comment: `$((10#${basename}+10)))` seems to work well with files named after positive numbers, e.g. `0010.png`, but not with some files named after negative numbers, e.g. `-008.png`. Why is the difference?

Comment: @Tim `$((10#008))` is `8`  and `$((-10#008))` is `-8` (this is what you meant by prepending `#10`). But `$((10#-008))` is `$((0 - 008))` and `008` is an illegal octal number

Comment: When `$basename` is `-008`, I think `$((10#${basename}))` is expanded to be `$((10#-008))` instead of `$((-10#008))`, or do I miss something? I am wondeirng whether `$basename` is negative or positive number makes any difference?  `10` in `$((10#${basename}))`  means base 10, so  why do the preceding zeros in `$basename`   indicate octal numbers.

Comment: @Tim You don't miss anything, `$((10#${basename}))` is expanded to `$((10#-008))` which means `$((10#0 - 008))` because the sign must be before the base specification (for the same reason you write -0xFF and not 0x-FF). For octal literal numbers, and leading zeros, see the bash manpage.

Comment: Thanks. I see `10#` will make a number become decimal, only in front of digits, not signs

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv
$ zmv -n '((-|)<->).(png|jpg)' '${(l:4::0:)$(($1 + 10))}.$3'
mv -- -002.jpg 0008.jpg
mv -- 0043.png 0053.png
mv -- 0044.png 0054.png
mv -- 0052.png 0062.png
mv -- -005.png 0005.png
mv -- -008.png 0002.png
```

(remove the `-n` to actually do it).

- `(-|)` glob: `-` or "": an optional `-`
- `<->` glob: any sequence of decimal digits (like `<x-y>` but without bounds).
- `${(l:4::0:)param}`: left padding (and truncation) of length 4 with zeros.
- `$(($1 + 10))`: the data captured by the first pair of `(...)` in the pattern, incremented by 10 (`zsh` doesn't have that issue that numbers with leading 0s are treated as octal; even if you set the `octalzeroes` option, that doesn't affect `zmv` which reverts to sane zsh options while it runs.

Answer (score -2):

`10#-008` will not make `-008` become decimal. I guess it is because `10#` needs to be in front of digits instead of signs.