# Is pattern `^-0+([0-9]+)` the same as `^-0+([1-9]+)`?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Jeff wrote at [errors in parameter expansion on filenames named after negative numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393880/errors-in-parameter-expansion-on-filenames-named-after-negative-numbers/479978#comment702644_393880)

> My best direction at this point is to do something like `[[ $b =~ ^-0+([0-9]+)$ ]] && b=-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to strip leading zeroes from possibly-negative numbers

I was wondering if the starting digit `0` in the pattern is necessary.
In other words, is pattern `^-0+([0-9]+)` the same as `^-0+([1-9]+)`?  Thanks.

Comment: Consider -0108 for example

Comment: For context for this question, my comment was intended to reduce confusion in dealing with negative numbers that looked like octal (leading zero).

Answer (score 4):

No, `^-0+([1-9]+)` doesn't match numbers like `-320`.

Edit: Rereading the pattern, there's actually two reasons `-320` doesn't match,

1. There are no `0`'s after the `-` (and the `+` says there has to be) - but that's not a difference between the two patterns (and probably a defiency in them)
2. There's a `0` after the first non-zero digit - that's the difference between the patterns.

Comment: Technically, `^-0+([1-9]+)` as a regexp matches on `-0320`, `^-0+([1-9]+)$` wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Whether `^-0+([0-9]+)` and `^-0+([1-9]+)` without the `$` will match on the same strings will depend on the locale. In the C/POSIX locale, they will match on the same strings (including `-01foo` and `-00230bar`) but what would be captured by the `(...)` could be different (for instance, the former would capture `230` on `-00230bar` while the latter `23`).

With the `$`, as indicated by @Henrik, they wouldn't match on the same strings. `^-0+([1-9]+)$` wouldn't match on `-00230`.

In other locales, your mileage may vary. For instance, in a `en_GB.UTF-8` locale on a Solaris 10 system, `^-0+([0-9]+)` would match on `-0⓿⓿12` because `⓿` is a character that sorts in-between `0` and `1` so is matched by `[0-1]` or `[0-9]` but not `^-0+([1-9]+)` as neither `0+` nor `[1-9]` would match on ⓿.

For completeness, to do that with standard `sh` syntax without having to rely on `bash`/`ksh93` extensions, you can do:

```
case ${b#-0} in
  ("$b" | "" | *[![:digit:]]*) echo >&2 no match;;
  (*) b=${b#"${b%%[!0-]*}"};;
esac
```

Here with the benefit that `[[:digit:]]` (as opposed to `[0-9]`) only matches on `0123456789`.

Comment: I said nothing about `$`'s, and it doesn't matter, the problem is with `0`'s after the first non-`0` digit, not necessarily last, consider eg. `-0108` (as @Jeff mentioned in a comment on the question), but you're right in saying that the locale might influence what's in `0-1`, I guess it's lucky that I've never encountered problems stemming from that.

Comment: @Henrik, because of the missing `$`, `^-0+([1-9]+)` will match on `-0108` and the `([1-9]+)` will capture only the `1`, that's the point I'm making here.

Comment: Right. Sorry, I didn't get that.